# Why is pandas.df.__getitem__ behavior "very hard to predict"?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, copy

I was checking [Pandas indexing docs discussion about returning views or copies](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy) when I ran into the following example and statement:

> ```
> dfmi = pd.DataFrame(...)
> dfmi['one']['second'] = value
> # becomes
> dfmi.__getitem__('one').__setitem__('second', value)
> ```
>
> See that `__getitem__` in there? Outside of simple cases, it’s very
>   hard to predict whether it will return a view or a copy (it depends on
>   the memory layout of the array, about which pandas makes no
>   guarantees), and therefore whether the `__setitem__` will modify
>   `dfmi` or a temporary object that gets thrown out immediately
>   afterward. **That's** what `SettingWithCopy` is warning you about!

How is it possible that the behavior of a fundamental procedure like `df.__getitem__` is not unequivocally defined? What are the design considerations supporting this behavior? Why does *"it depends on the memory layout of the array, about which pandas makes no guarantees"*?

Comment: Because *"it depends on the memory layout of the array, about which pandas makes no guarantees"*.